# How to save a hybrid Tensorflow and Pennylane model?

Tags: machine-learning, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning, pennylane

I implemented a hybrid model with Keras and Pennylane that looks like this:
[image]

The quantum layer is basically a quantum circuit converted to a keras layer with the `qml.qnn.KerasLayer()` function.
Now I am trying to save and export this model so I can run it in other python scripts, so what do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation of Pennylane claimed that we can just use `model.save(SAVE_PATH)` to save our hybrid model just like any other normal Tensorflow model. However, referring to the question I posted [Error loading saved hybrid quantum (pennylane + tensorflow keras) model: Unknown layer: 'KerasLayer'](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/34916/25997), I had trouble loading the model (.h5 or .keras format) that I saved with that model.

I found the alternative method - save the saves with `model.save_weights(WEIGHTS_PATH)` to save the weights. To load the model, just define a new model with the same model structure, then use `model.load_weights(WEIGHTS_PATH)` to load the weights from the saved path. This worked perfectly fine.